# Field Collection, adding new elements to it in form

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a $form with a field collection "field_definition" which has 2 fields in it with unlimited cardinality. I can kind of create the fields by doing this in hook_form_alter:

```
$field_definition_template = $form['field_definition']['und'][0];

for($k=0;$k<count($column_names);$k++)
{
    $form['field_definition']['und'][$k] = $field_definition_template;
    $form['field_definition']['und'][$k]['#delta'] = $k;
}
```

The problem is the names are wrong, the ids are wrong and pretty much everything else. Is there a way to do this correctly?

Comment: Hey Chris, what exactly do you mean the names and ids are wrong? If you're not getting the structure (a.k.a names and IDs) you'd expect from `$form_state['values']` for example, make sure you set `$form['#tree'] = TRUE`. Otherwise the tree structure gets flattened. I can't really get what you are trying to achieve here and doesn't work...

Comment: It is pretty hard to explain, but I am basically trying to create fields for an unlimited cardinality field collection on the server side. There is always one of the field collections created by default, but in order to add another one you need to change the delta and a bunch of other data such as ids.

Comment: What type is this field: is it standard FAPI or CCK? If it's standard FAPI then you're code looks OK, you should get what you want: a bunch of extra fields depending on `count($columng_names)`. In this case is the issue that the fields generated are not the same as the default one? I'm just trying to understand you're issue a bit better.

Comment: These are CCK fields I am trying to clone in drupal 7. (CCK is now in core)

Comment: Yes, you're right CCK is now in core. I really don't see why your code wouldn't work. Unless those fields are some special type and they need some other params set up, that code should do the trick. BTW, what type is the 'original' one and are you using a special widget to display it? E.g. File has File Upload and Image.

Comment: The fields are text fields in the field collection. The other problem is they are unlimited cardinality and form alter gets called again when the add more items button is pressed.

Comment: OK, now we're getting somewhere. So, you want _a)_ to have an **add more** button which keeps on adding extra fields _b)_ you know from the beginning that you'll have X number of clone fields (`count($column_names)`) _c)_ a combination of both: you'll present the form with X clone fields but also have an **add more** button.

Comment: Ever work this out? Having issues with field collections myself in an AJAX multistep form.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to work with [hook_field_presave()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_presave/7) in order to add the values to the field itself. Using Form API on fields does work, sometimes, but it will be cleaner if you switch over to using the [Field API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/group/field/7) directly.